# I want to add multiple data with same name in php

Tags: php

I want to add multiple data with same form control name. Code working fine but only last record is added to the database. Please solve the problem as soon as possible:

```
$acname=$_POST['name'];
$acmob=$_POST['mob'];
$acgen=$_POST['gender'];
$atype=$_POST['accompany'];
foreach($acname as $aname)
{
    foreach($acmob as $amob)
    {
        foreach($acgen as $agender)
        {
            if($_POST['accompany']=="ac_reg")
            {
                $qry="insert into accompanyReg(name, mob, email, gender) values('$aname', '$amob', '', '$agender')";    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as soon as possible is not possible

Comment: You must add your database-connection function after your `$qry` parameter, inside your 3. `foreach`-loop.

Comment: in your form multiple data insertation form ... there are name ,mob,gender...fields are more then 1 with same name ?

Comment: yes its more than one with same name